# Programmatically get directory from which Eclipse is running from

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, p2

I need to get the physical location, for example C:\dev\indigo\plugins. Not what Platform.getInstallationDirectory() or System.getProperties().get( "osgi.install.area"); return.

Comment: Platform.getInstallLocation() does give you the install directory, so what is wrong with this?

Comment: In addition to greg's comment: if you're interested in <...>/plugins location, check this wiki http://wiki.eclipse.org/Configurator

Comment: @IlyaShinkarenko My mistake. I was in Eclipse Runtime running from source and obviously it was displaying locations relative to my workspace. In product locations are correct.